# npm is not recognized as a command in the middle of npm install

Tags: angular, npm-install

I receive the following error in the middle of running `npm install` on the **package.json** file of an Angular 10 application:

> 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
> program or batch file.

I know that npm is installed because I started the install with the command `npm install`. So, I don't understand why the installation of NPM packages for the Angular application fails partway through with this message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact reason why this was happening is not certain, but it seems to have started when I updated the package `jasmine-core` from `~3.5.0` to `~3.10.0`.

After I uninstalled Node.js and deleted all folders from previous Node.js installations **and** after I updated `jasmine-core` from `~3.5.0` to `~3.8.0` (instead of `~3.10.0`), then I was able to run `npm install` again without errors.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what the issue is here, but you have three options which have a chance of working.

- using `npx npm install` instead of `npm install`
- reinstalling npm via `npm i -g npm` (this automatically picks the newest version)
- reinstalling `node` (I put this one last because it's not worth it for slow internet connections and it's also a waste of time in general considering the above two should work fine)